# Resizing a select multiple list with the size of the dialog box

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a select list inside a dialog box:

```
<div id='Dialog' title='Title'>
    <div id='list_container'>
        <select id='file_list' multiple='multiple'>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm populating `file_list` in javascript. The css for `list_container` and 'file_list` look like this:

```
#list_container {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px black solid;
    margin: auto;
}

#file_list {
    border: none;
}
```

The `file_list` opens inside a dialog box and typically has many options(>20). When the dialog box pops up, the list shows about 10 entries and I can scroll down to other entries. However, I want the list to expand vertically when I resize the dialog box vertically (i.e. the list should show more than 10 entries depending on the vertical space available in the dialog box). How can I do this? I tried doing a few things like setting the height css attribute for `file_list` to auto , but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is similar to the answer provided by SOliver. I solved it by firing a function at the dialog resize event, and modifying the size attribute of the select-list depending on the height of the dialog box:

```
$('#Dialog').dialog({
  height: 460,
  width: 500,
  //Add a function on the dialog resize event
  resize: function(event, ui) {
    var default_height = 460;     //default height 
    var new_height = ui.size.height; //Gives height after resize
      if (new_height > default_height) {
        var list = $('#file_list');
        var row_height = ((flist.height())/(flist.attr('size'))); 
                             //Get height of one row
        var extra_space = new_height-default_height;
        var list_newSize = Math.floor(extra_space/row_height) + 11; 
                            //11 is the default or minimum 'size' of file_list
        flist.attr('size',list_newSize);
      }
  }
);
```

Make sure you set the height and width of the `div` that contains select list to auto. Now the size of the list should scale with the size of the dialog box.

Though this works, it seems like an ad-hoc solution. Any there any more elegant ways to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use something similar to the following either called during an event call or otherwise at a point when the elements have been added to the body

```
var width = document.getElementById("list_container").offsetWidth;
document.getElementById("file_list").style.width = width;
```